# How to change the tabbar selected image using storyboard

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, storyboard

I have created application using storyboard and has `TabBarController` with 5 tabs.
Each tab has tabicon and `tab title`. When a tab is selected I want to change the `tabbar` icon.
How can I do using `storyboard`?

Comment: In Xcode 6 you would think you can do this with the new "Selected Image" field in the Attributes Inspector for the Tab Bar item, but for some reason that results in a blank image when selected, as of Xcode 6.1.1 anyway. However, there is a workaround detailed here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26802597/650558

Answer (score 12):

`- (void)setFinishedSelectedImage:withFinishedUnselectedImage:` is deprecated. If you're using storyboards, it's as simple as

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
UIImage* selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"settings-active"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
tabBarItem0.selectedImage = selectedImage;
```

**EDIT**

In Swift:

```
var settingsItem = self.tabBar.items?[0] as UITabBarItem
settingsItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home-selected")
```

Note that this code belongs in the `viewDidLoad` override of your `UITabBarController` subclass.

Answer (score 1):

I have got it.

Subclass `UITabBarController` - `MyTabBarController`

Over write viewDid load :

write

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem0 = [self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:0];
    [tabBarItem0 setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"selectedimage.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"image.png"]];
```

like this set for all the tabbar items and in story board set the tabBar controller to `MyTabBarController`. It's working fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can now do this easily in storyboard. On each tabviewcontroller that you have, it should contain a Tab Bar Item in the hierarchy (looks like a little blue star), Click on this and the settings on the right should look like the image below. The tab bar title & image can be changed here.

[image]

Answer (score -2):

Below code will change tabbar image in selection:

```
UITabBarItem *tabBarItem = [[tabbar items] objectAtIndex:0];
[tabBarItem setFinishedSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img_hover.png"] withFinishedUnselectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"img.png"]];
```

change identifier to custom and add image[image]

Comment: I have 5 tabs where should I write this code. In each viewController.?