# Setting Selected Image in Tab Bar Controller with Storyboard

Tags: ios, xcode5

I am using Storyboarding and I have a tab bar controller with five tabs. In the storyboard, I am able to set the image for the tab bar item. Apple docs suggest to have two icons for each tab bar item - one for selected and one for the unselected state.

I am not able to figure out how I can do this using storyboard.

Comment: Simple answer to a straightforward question: You can't, it's code only (for the time being at least). `initWithTitle:image:selectedImage:`

Answer (score 150, accepted):

You can use storyboard to set selected image of tabbar. I tried and it worked for me.
Select the UITabbarItem and add a run-time attribute 'selectedImage', select Type as 'Image' and give the name of your image as its value.

[image: Setting selected image of Tabbar using storyboard]

I am using XCode 6.0 and my minimum deployment target is iOS 8.0.

Comment: The new version of XCode has a "Selected Image" field in the Attributes Inspector but it doesn't seem to work. Thankfully this answer worked for me.

Comment: This is great, I've been searching for how to fix this for hours. Thanks for providing the answer!

Comment: I have tried same. But, not working for me. I am not sure what is reason.

Comment: Same issue.  This worked.  The built in UI for IB did not.  2-16-2015  Xcode 6.1.1

Comment: As of Xcode 6.4 and August 2015, this bug is still affecting Xcode. Amazing. Thanks for this answer!

Comment: Thanks. If it's not working, one might want to try cleaning first.

Comment: Testing on Xcode 7 - the Selected Image field in the Attributes Inspector of UITabBarItem seems to work fine for me now. Testing in iOS 9. Not sure if it will still work on iOS 8 devices though. EDIT: Tested in 8.4 simulator - works there too with the selected image field in storyboard

Comment: Now you can use from the Inspector the Bar Item -> Image field, watch out NOT the Tab Bar Item -> Selected Image.

Comment: the xcode (8.3.1) is crashing every time that i try to add

Comment: Works. Thanks in xcode (9.3.2) for swift 4 (deployed for iOS 10+)

Comment: In Xcode 11, I've found that you need to use the image attribute that is under `Bar Item` in the attribute inspector.

Answer (score 29):

**Here is complete solution for selected/unselected image in Tabbar For XCode >= 8:**

- Go to Image assets -> select image
- Select Render AS: "Original Image"

[image]

- After that go to storyboard -> Select Tabbar Item
- Under Attribute Inspectors, set "Selected Image" & "Image" as shown
  in following screenshot, that`s it:

[image]

Comment: This worked for me. Actually, it was not necessary to set Render AS: "Original Image", the default value did it also.

Answer (score 17):

In XCode 8 and above you can simply do it in Image assets,Just select the image and select Render as "Original Image". (Please check attached image)..Have FUN :)[image]

Comment: This is a VERY IMPORTANT piece, as simply setting the UIImage to the selectedImage did nothing for me. (I must note, I was doing it programmatically) Thanks @Infaz

Answer (score 12):

Yes, this cannot be done using storyboards - needs code to be written.

In the `UINavigationViewController`'s `viewDidLoad` method, we can write the following code -

```
UITabBar *tabBar = self.tabBar;

UITabBarItem *targetTabBarItem = [[tabbar items] objectAtIndex:0]; // whichever tab-item
UIImage *selectedIcon = [UIImage imageNamed:@"name-of-selected-image.png"];
[targetTabBarItem setSelectedImage:selectedIcon];
```

Comment: There is no class called `UINavigationViewController` and if you meant `UINavigationController`, it has no property called `tabBar`.

Comment: The actual first line of code should be like: `UITabBar *tabBar = self.navigationController.tabBarController.tabBar;`

Answer (score 7):

You can now do this easily in storyboard. On each tabviewcontroller that you have, it should contain a Tab Bar Item in the hierarchy (looks like a little blue star), Click on this and the settings on the right should look like the image below. The tab bar title & image can be changed here.

[image]

Comment: @DavidNelson you can only fill in the image section, you must leave the selected image section empty for it to work.

Comment: What is the "Selected Image" for in this case? Why is there a separate section for "Tab Bar Item" and "Bar Item"? If I select one of the system items it works fine -- custom images fail.

Comment: I am getting blue square in place of the image. More details please on how to get it work? I am using xcode 7.1. May be there are some constraints? height width etc. ?

Comment: Hi! I'm getting a colored square in the place of the custom image i want when the tab bar is selected. This happens when I add a selected image using the storyboard as shown in your answer. Any idea why this is happening? I'm using Xcode 9.2

Answer (score 6):

I think that the easiest way is setting the image from the Inspector.
you have a field called **Bar Item -> Image**, and it is in there where you have to set the image name.
Watch out, not confuse with the **Tab Bar Item -> Selected Image**

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the new Xcode 8 you can do in Storyboard without needing to defined the runtime attributes as is suggested in the high pointed answer.

[image: Print Screen Tab Bar item]

Don't forget that image should have this size:

- @1x : about 25 x 25
- @2x : about 50 x 50
- @3x : about 75 x 75

Comment: Was very confused on how to set the default tab, thanks for showing this.

Comment: I'm glad I could help :D

Answer (score 6):

SWIFT 3.0 --> 
The Ideal way to set your tab bar button images is as follows :

first set the images you want to use for the button :

```
    let homeImage = UIImage(named: "TabHome")
    let homeTappedImage = UIImage(named: "TabHomeRed")
```

then set the button of type UITabButtonItem :

```
    let homeButton = UITabBarItem(title: homeText, image: homeImage, selectedImage: homeTappedImage)

    //with this method you set the image when the button is not selected 
    homeButton.image = homeImage?.withRenderingMode(UIImageRenderingMode.alwaysOriginal)


    //with this method you set the image when the button is selected 
    homeButton.selectedImage = homeTappedImage?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Answer (score 3):

The icon should be set in the corresponding view controller. When doing this you're free to rearrange the order of view controllers inside the storyboards main tab controller without having to change the code (`objectAtIndex:0`) for each and every icon.

Put the following line into the `viewDidLoad` method:

```
 if (self.navigationController.viewControllers.count < 2)
     self.navigationController.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image-selected.png"];
```

The `if`condition makes sure that the button is only changed for the top most view controller. This is required when you reuse view controllers in a navigation hierarchy as sub view controllers.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer, noting that the "corresponding view controller" is the `UINavigationController`'s root view controller.