# swift - Tab Bar selected image is not displayed

Tags: swift, xcode

I have a different `Selected Image` for each `Tab Bar Items`. I gave the correct file name under Attributes Inspector -> Tab Bar Item -> Selected Image. But all I got is blue tint over my images. `Selected Image` does not displays.

Tried setting the image under `User Defined Runtime Attributes`. This doesn't work.

Comment: This question appears to be a duplicate (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386101/setting-selected-image-in-tab-bar-controller-with-storyboard)), but to be fair, from the comments on the linked question, it is clear that with new versions of Xcode the question is once again apparently un-answered.

Comment: were you able to resolve the issue?

Comment: I created a custom tabbarcontroller.swift and change selected images there. And it work. Storyboard things didn't worked for me

Answer (score 11):

Select image in *Assets.xcassets* and set its 'Render as' property to *Original image*.

[image]

Comment: This will help you. https://mobiletechfeast.blogspot.in/2014/04/image-rendering-modes-in-ios7-apple.html

Comment: Set as Template Image if you want to keep the tint color