# Image is not showing up for tab bar item

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I uploaded an image to assets folder and assigned the image to 1x, 2x and 3x. 
selected the table view controller of the respective tab bar item -> selected the Attributes -> assigned the image to the image field in the Bar Items section.

After running the application a Blue Square box is showing up on selection and Grayed out square box is showing up on selection of a different bar item.

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: refer this, http://stackoverflow.com/a/26802597/6742121. Use storyboard and try again.

Comment: I tried this, and it did not work. I am on Xcode8.0 and iOS m, if that mattwrs

Answer (score 122, accepted):

Go to Assets folder.
Select your tab image.
On the right side under Attributes you will find "Render As".
Select "Original Image".

Comment: This seems to be working. However, the image is going over the tab bar boundary. Any easy fix?

Comment: for fix image issue then you need to set image size 30*30

Comment: as @KKRocks said, you need to set the size of the images using Apple's [Human Interface Guidelines]( https://developer.apple.com/ios/human-interface-guidelines/graphics/custom-icons/)

Comment: This worked for Xcode Version 8.3.3 (8E3004b) July 2017

Comment: Render as Original image is working fine but selecting tab bar indicator colour is not getting change for that image.

Comment: you are saviour @BB

Comment: thanks a lot for your solution, i keep search tell i found your answer

Comment: My problem was that I set the image in the "Selected Image" field instead of the "Image" field for the UITabBarItem.

Comment: I faced the issue on iOS 11 and it was solved with the given solution. Now, with ios 13 the issue appeared again. Any fixes?

Comment: Set as Template Image if you want to keep the tint color

Answer (score 23):

When you click on a tab bar icon in one of your view controllers, on the right hand side is where you set the image. What's misleading is that there are two places to set the image in the right sidebar. Under `Tab Bar Item > System Item (custom)` below that selecting the custom image. Then right below that whole first set there is `Bar Item > Image`. Mine wouldn't show up until I set the `Bar Item > Image` as well.

Answer (score 3):

If you follow `B B`'s answer, the image will always render in original form in all the places.

for my tabbar implementation i had to do the following

```
tabBarItem.selectedImage = UIImage(named: "home").withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal);
tabBarItem.image =  = UIImage(named: "home");
```

So here the image will be rendering as original when the tab is SELECTED (ie, tint will not be applied) and tint will be applied to the tab bar item image when that tab is not selected

@kishor0011: This should fix your problem.

Answer (score 2):

add tab bar item under view controller, if you embed in view controller in navigation controller tab bar item must be come under Navigation controller.

- View controller when icon not shown

[image: view controller when icon not shown]

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted](http://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers).

Answer (score 2):

[image: Screen Shot for Convert Image Render]

First drop your image in the Assets or Images section then click on the image and show to option for Render As in the right side menu. So change the option from default to Original Image same as shown in above screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem due to the tint color on my `UIBarButtonItem` this did the trick!

```swift
BarButtonItem.image = UIImage(named: "yourImage")?.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)
```

Answer (score 0):

Just choose an image in the Bar item section. About the selectedImage, check this [selectedImage Apple developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbaritem/1617072-selectedimage)