# Change ViewController from Tabbar

Tags: swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

I have a `UITabBarController` with 3 tabs and a `SettingsVC` where you can choose the appearance of `MainVC` (There are 2 different `ViewControllers` which based on what user prefers should be shown as the `MainVC`).

I made the application and it works but it's really buggy, cause I was just pushing the `ViewControllers` on top of each other, and in some certain conditions you see bugs while switching `tabs`.

> Main.storyboard

[image]

Here is some part of my code(after trying a lot of stuff) which changes the VC's based on `UserDefaults`

> CheckSettingsStatus.swift

```
//
// Check for Double Column Settings and navigate to Double Column VC
//
func checkMainVCViewStatusAndNavigateAcordingly(){
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: KEY_MAIN_VC_VIEW) == 1{
        //let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        //appDel.goToDoubleMainVC()

        let mainVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "DoubleColumnMainVC") as! DoubleColumnMainVC
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] = mainVC
        //navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: false)

        var navigationArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
        print("Number of VCs = \(String(describing: navigationArray?.count))")
        if navigationArray?.count == nil{
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: false)
        }else{
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
        //            self.navigationController?.viewControllers = navigationArray!
    }
}


//
// same as function above but goes to MainVC
//
func checkDoubleColumnMainVCViewStatusAndNavigateAcordingly(){
    if UserDefaults.standard.integer(forKey: KEY_MAIN_VC_VIEW) == 0{
        //            let appDel = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        //            appDel.goToMainVC()
        let mainVC = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "MainVC") as! MainVC
        self.navigationController?.viewControllers[0] = mainVC

        var navigationArray = self.navigationController?.viewControllers
        print("Number of VCs = \(String(describing: navigationArray?.count))")
        if navigationArray?.count == nil{
            navigationController?.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: false)
        }else{
            self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
        }
        //            self.navigationController?.viewControllers = navigationArray!
    }
}
```

With this in ViewWillAppear of both this Controllers I call these functions to switch accordingly.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Can I push controllers from UITabBarController and not NavigationController? something like:

```
tabBarController.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: false)
```

instead of:

```
navigationController.pushViewController(mainVC, animated: false)
```

Thank you in advance

**UPDATE:**

In my best case when everything works nicely, on first launch of the app (to the second `mainVC`) the `Buttons` in `NavBar` doesn't work.

**EDIT:**

I just realised that the `NavigationBar` that I'm seeing above my `SecondMainVC` is the `NavigationBar` from `MainVC`, that is why the buttons are not working. how is that possible?

Comment: First of all you can't push controller from tabBarController.Instead you can set a particular viewController to switch using tabBarController.selectedIndex = 1

Comment: @Vikky if I get it right, if `selectedIndex` indicates one of my VCs then doesn't work, because the first tab is `MainVC`, second is `CategoriesVC` and 3rd is `SettingsVC`. Because I don't have my `SecondMainVC` in another tab, I just want to conditionally show another VC on first tab. Did I get it right? Did you understand what I mean?

Comment: Image you provided is very blurry so checking from it is very difficult.Now coming back to your question yes you got it right what i said.Now if you want to open another VC in your first tab you have to replace your view controller programmatically .

Comment: @Vikky I'll try to change the pic, but I don't get how I can use selected index to change that, could you please write some code? Also I just tried assigning VC directly e.g. `tabBarController?.selectedViewController = mainVC` but on launch the app crashed.

Comment: @Vikky photo changed, I hope it's better now

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I faced same issue while trying to develop a tab bar controller in storyboard , for this reason I found that the best way is to implement it by code. 
so you can make your code look like this :

1) create a a sub class of UITabController and let it conform to UITabBarControllerDelegate

```
  class TabBarVC: UITabBarController , UITabBarControllerDelegate {
```

2)then write this method in your class to initialize the tabs in your project:

```
  private func settingUpTabBarAndInitializingViewControllers(){

    //self delagting
    self.delegate = self 

    //home tab
    let homeStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.StoryBoards.homeStoryboard, bundle: nil)
    let homeVC = homeStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.ControllersIDs.homeScreen) as! HomeVC

    // shop tab
    let shopStoybaord = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.StoryBoards.shopStoryboard, bundle: nil)
    let shopVC = shopStoybaord.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.ControllersIDs.shopScreen) as! ShopVC

    //offers tab
    let offersStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.StoryBoards.offersStoryboard, bundle: nil)
    let offersVC = offersStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.ControllersIDs.offersScreen) as! OffersVC

    //more tab
    let moreStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: Constants.StoryBoards.MoreScreenStoryboard, bundle: nil)
    let moreVC = moreStoryboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: Constants.ControllersIDs.moreVCScreen) as! MoreOptionsTVC


    //setting VCs
    self.viewControllers = [homeVC , shopVC , offersVC , moreVC]


    //setting buttons

    //buttons images
    let homeImage = UIImage(named: "TabHome")
    let shopImage = UIImage(named : "TabShop")
    let offerImage = UIImage(named: "TabOffers")
    let moreImage = UIImage(named: "TabMenu")


    // buttons shakhsiyan
    let homeButton = UITabBarItem(title: homeText, image: homeImage, selectedImage: homeTappedImage)
    let shopButton = UITabBarItem(title: shopText, image: shopImage, selectedImage: shopTappedImage)
    let offersButton = UITabBarItem(title: offersText, image: offerImage, selectedImage: offersTappedImage)     
    let moreButton = UITabBarItem(title: moreText, image: moreImage, selectedImage: moreTappedImage)


    homeVC.tabBarItem = homeButton
    shopVC.tabBarItem = shopButton
    offersVC.tabBarItem = offersButton
    moreVC.tabBarItem = moreButton

}
```

P.S. you can add tabs as much as you want and while scrolling in them you wont face any bug,

make sure to have only one navigation controller before your tab bar controller.

Comment: I set the it up but I have no navigationBar anymore. what could be the problem? from the beginning I have a TabBar (that has the above class) and after it is a NavigationController which its root is my homeVC. (I deleted other NavControllers as you said

Comment: the problem is that your adding a navigation bar after the tab bar controller ,remove the navigation bar of the homeVC , and make sure that you have only one navigation bar before the tab bar controller (having the tab bar controller as a root view controller ), and this navigation bar will be responsible for all the other controllers following HomeVC

Comment: Oh I didn't know how to do that and thought it's not possible, ok it seems I am close, now I have no buttons, logos titles in any navBar, that is the only remaining thing (even though in viewdidload of each VC I set them programmatically)

Comment: i posted the solution for your problem in the below link
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386101/setting-selected-image-in-tab-bar-controller-with-storyboard/47830995#47830995)

Comment: ahh sorry , 
to set the navigation bar buttons you need in each tab ,
you have to  set them in the main tabBarVC,
and by delegates then set their actions to each Tab.

Answer (score 3):

Check this hope it helps
[image]

Ok you can create a DEMO to see how thing works.After that you can implement it in your project.I know it may not look good to you but read it once and see image attached i am sure will get your answer.

1.I have created two UIViewControllers with the UITabBarController.

2.I have created class ItemFirstVC,ItemTwoVC and assigned to UIViewControllers in storyboard

3.Each controller is embedded in UINavigationController

4.Create a custom class of UITabBarController

5.Assign it to UITabBarController in storyboard

6.Now Each UIViewController has a button named as Firs Button,Second Button

7.From each button i have connected Action Segue to one more controller as you can see in image.

8.Now i have created a third UIViewController which is separate from UITabBarController.

9.Now we will load that Third UIViewController in UITabBarController

10.Create one more class ItemThirdVC and assign it to third UIViewController.

11.It also has a button named as third button action segued to one more UIViewController

12.Now switch to custom class of UITabBarContoller

```
// variable required to see work in action
var count = 0
 class CustomTabBarController: UITabBarController {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    // remember to assign delegate
    delegate = self

}
  // this delegate indicates whether this tab should be selected or not
 extension CustomTabBarController : UITabBarControllerDelegate{
func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
    // switch to UIViewController tabs multiple times
    count = count + 1
    if(count == 5){
        // when count reaches 5 a new controller will load
    let navigationController = viewController as? UINavigationController
    guard navigationController != nil else {return true}
    let viewController = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "ItemThreeVC")
    guard let vc = viewController else {return true}
    navigationController?.setViewControllers([vc], animated: false)
    }
    return true
}
 }
```