# Change Image when clicking tabbar

Tags: swift, xcode, tabbar

I want to be able to click on my profile tab and change the image to a more bolder profile icon. I have two images. How can I change the picture when the user selects on a tab?

```swift
if selectedIndex == 3 {
            self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items?[3].image = UIImage(named: "AppIcon")
        }
```

This is in the tab bar view controller. I think this will only run once. I want to make it so it runs every time they click on it

Comment: Can you share your code thus far?

Comment: there it is, the code

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting Selected Image in Tab Bar Controller with Storyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21386101/setting-selected-image-in-tab-bar-controller-with-storyboard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is function you can use to detect selected tab in the [UITabBarControllerDelegate](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate)

```
tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, 
                 didSelect viewController: UIViewController)
```